# create 2 grouped products with different attributes using only one theme

Tags: theme, grouped-products

I want to create grouped products. I will explain my need with examples.

Grouped product 1

```
Productname  length height price
2             2      2      2
```

Grouped product 2

```
Productname  length height width price
2               2    2      2     2
```

I can create Grouped product 1 and Grouped product 2 by creating attributes "length, height, width "
and by creating 2 themes.

```
Theme 1 => grouped1.phtml => LENGTH , HEIGHT
Theme 2 => grouped2.phtml => LENGTH , HEIGHT, WIDTH
```

Is it possible to Create both Grouped Products with only one theme.

Let me know if you need any clarifications.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need to create theme for it? just create two attribute sets...

Comment: hi, please see below 2 comments.

Comment: to create different grouped products, diff attribute sets are enough.

How to display in frontend.?

visit this: http://pastebin.com/SSYSWh77

check the line number 116 117 136 137, I can create Grouped product 1 using above code & assigning product to theme 1.

Comment: I can create Grouped product 2 by using another attribute set [length , height, width ]

But If i want to display grouped product 2 with length , height, width by selcting theme 1, its not possible,

because check the 116 117 136 137 in above link. 

If I add Width on 118, Than in Width will also display in grouped product 1. 

but I need width only in grouped product 2.

let me know if you need any clarifications.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution:
use

```
<div class="Cell" id="forlength" style="display:none"><?php echo $this->__('LENGTH') ?></div>
<div class="Cell" id="forheight" style="display:none"><?php echo $this->__('HEIGHT') ?></div> 
<div class="Cell" id="forwidth" style="display:none"><?php echo $this->__('WIDTH') ?></div>
```

on line 118
while on line 138 use :

```
<?php if($_item->getData('length')): ?><script>$('forlength').show();</script><div class="Cell"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getData('length')) ?></div><?php endif; ?>
<?php if($_item->getData('height')): ?><script>$('forheight').show();</script><div class="Cell"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getData('height')) ?></div><?php endif; ?>
<?php if($_item->getData('width')): ?><script>$('forwidth').show();</script><div class="Cell"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getData('width')) ?></div><?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: hi, unfortunately that did't woked for me. In both Grouped product 1 and also in Grouped product 2 , "WIDTH"
is displaying. I want to display "WIDTH" and its attribute values only in GROUPED PRODUCT 2. But It's displaying also in "GROUPED PRODUCT 1". is i have to do something else? thanks in advance.

Comment: well the condition i suggested is to check, if it has value for width, then it will show the width. does it also show any value of width on group product 1 or just the heading?

Comment: firstly, sorry for delayed reply.

hi,

that's awesome, you just done a great job. 

Attribute code related issue is solved. Now only Length and height values are displying.

If i have Length and Height, only Length and Height is displaying.

If i have Length and Height and width, only Length and Height and width is displaying.

but one small problem is there. For some grouped products, I want to display " Length and height"

for another grouped product, I want to display " Depth and Width on frontend.

Is there anything we can do for this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: you can just use the same condition for all attributes. It will print them only if it will get the values for them

Comment: attributes are just fine, I am telling about line 116 and 117 .  I want Length and height" for one grouped product, I want to display " Depth and Width" for another grouped product. how i can do this?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please accept by clicking the tick so it turns to green and vote it.

Comment: You need to use the same logic for other attributes also, let me update the answer for your help

Comment: hi, sure. i will do it. please help me for last things. please visit this links :http://schoolboards4.newtrendzonline.com/index.php/projector-screens-9/tripod-projection-screens-605.html

http://schoolboards4.newtrendzonline.com/index.php/projector-screens-9/tripod-mtm.html

If I want to Display "DEPTH" in frontend instead of "WIDTH", how i can do that?

Comment: means I need to display  "WIDTH" for one grouped product and "Depth" for another grouped product? please help me to find solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16860/discussion-between-mtm-and-baby-in-magento).

Comment: hi, i don't know how to chat here.... 

as i know your gmail, please check your gmail

Comment: follow this link http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16860/discussion-between-mtm-and-baby-in-magento

Comment: no, In one grouped product On top, it should display " Length, Height"

In another grouped product On top, it should display " Length, Depth"

Comment: not about rows, 
 
no, In one grouped product on first row, it should display " Length, Height" In another grouped product On first row , it should display " Length, Depth.

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: hi, I updated your answer in line 116 117 118 please visit link : http://schoolboards4.newtrendzonline.com/index.php/projector-screens-9/tripod-projection-screens-605.html and http://schoolboards4.newtrendzonline.com/index.php/projector-screens-9/tripod-mtm.html

Comment: hi, sorry if i told unclearly. i will clear my needs, please check the question.

On Grouped product 2, instead of Productname  length height width price, 
i need Productname  depth height width price,

How to replace depth by length in grouped product 2. but i need length only in grouped product 1.

Comment: how do u differentiate between group product 1 and group product 2?

Comment: thanks a lot for reply. by names if we differentiate Grouped product 1 and Grouped product 2, by attributes, we can differentiate by 
giving length & width attributes values in grouped product 1 and depth and width values in grouped product 2.
by the first row, in Grouped product 1 => Productname  length width price and Grouped product 2 => Productname  depth width price.

please let me know if you need any clarifications.

thanks in advance.